# How to get poll voters of multiple polls in a Telegram group without using any bots?

Tags: python, telegram-api

I've been trying to generate a list of voters for several official Telegram polls.
I studied the documentation of `python-telegram-bot` but the problem is that I think it requires a bot to join the group and collect the polls information.
Is there any way to collect the polls data without having to add a bot and use my own account for viewing the polls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing similar thing using playwright Python API. All you need to do is store your authentication as a json file. Then you have to use the file using your account. You need some knowledge about HTML and CSS. You can easily get the needed information using beautifulsoup module.